# Can we say anything about the relationship between these functors?

Tags: combinatorics, soft-question, vector-spaces, category-theory

I am working with a category $\mathcal{C}$ and two functors $F:\mathcal{C}\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$-$\mathbf{Vect}$ and $G:\mathcal{C}^{\operatorname{op}}\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$-$\mathbf{Vect}$ where $\mathbb{R}$-$\mathbf{Vect}$ is the category of real vector spaces with linear maps.

For each object $X\in\mathcal{C}$, suppose that $F(X)=G(X)$ and *furthermore* suppose we have a bilinear map $B_X : F(X)\times F(X)\rightarrow F(X)$. Let $m_X :F(X)\otimes F(X)\rightarrow F(X)$ denote the unique linear map induced by $B_X$ on the tensor product by its UMP. Then for each morphism $\eta:X\rightarrow Y$ in $\mathcal{C}$ there are linear maps
$$F(\eta)\otimes G(\operatorname{id}_Y): F(X)\otimes G(Y)\rightarrow F(Y)\otimes G(Y)$$

$$F(\operatorname{id}_X)\otimes G(\eta):F(X)\otimes G(Y)\rightarrow F(X)\otimes G(X)$$

such that the diagram below (in $\mathbb{R}$-$\mathbf{Vect}$) commutes:

[image]

My very open question is: does this give me any (categorically interesting) information about these two functors?

**Edit**: this question was edited in response to a comment which pointed out the original question made no sense without $B_X$ (you cannot multiply vectors in general vector spaces!), which I had forgotten to mention. I hope that this has fixed the issue and that the question now makes sense.

**Second edit - description of the functors**: This question is my attempt to understand my "categorisation" of Razborov's [flag algebra paper](https://www.math.ias.edu/csdm/files/05-06/arazborov_flag_algebras.pdf). The category $\mathcal{C}$ is the category of finite models ("types") of a theory $T$ in a first-order language $L$ containing only predicate symbols, with elementary embeddings as morphisms (a specific example being the category of finite graphs with embeddings where you cannot introduce new edges in the image of an embedding). For each type $\sigma$ there is a set of $\sigma$-*flags*, denoted $\mathcal{F}^\sigma$. A $\sigma$-flag is an object in the coslice category $\sigma/\mathcal{C}$. Then we have a real vector space $\mathcal{A}^\sigma$ obtained by taking all formal linear combinations of $\sigma$-flags and quotienting out by a certain relation (relation (4)). This becomes a commutative associative unital algebra over $\mathbb{R}$ with a bilinear product (Lemma 2.4 in the paper).

For an embedding $\eta: \sigma\rightarrow \tau$ in $\mathcal{C}$ there is an algebra homomorphism $\pi^\eta : \mathcal{A}^\sigma\rightarrow\mathcal{A}^\tau$, called an *upward operator* (§ 2.3.1), which sends a $\sigma$-flag $F$ to a sum over all $\tau$-flags $\tau\xrightarrow{\theta}M$ of a certain size that are isomorphic to $F$ (as $\sigma$-flags) when you pull back along $\eta:\sigma\rightarrow \tau$ and delete the nodes in the image of $\theta$ but not $\theta\eta$. This behaves functorially and gives us an "upward functor" $\uparrow (-):\mathcal{C}\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$-$\mathbf{Alg}$, where $\uparrow (\sigma) = \mathcal{A}^\sigma$ and $\uparrow(\eta) = \pi^\eta$.

There is also a *downward operator* (§ 2.2) $[\cdot]_\eta:\mathcal{A}^\tau \rightarrow\mathcal{A}^\sigma$ (which is a linear map but **not** an algebra homomorphism) that sends a $\tau$-flag $\tau\xrightarrow{\theta} M$ to the $\sigma$-flag $\sigma\xrightarrow{\theta\eta} M$ multiplied by the probability that a random injective map $\tau\xrightarrow{\phi}M$ satisfying $\phi\eta = \theta\eta$ is a model embedding *and* the $\tau$-flags $\tau\xrightarrow{\phi}M$ and $\tau\xrightarrow{\theta}M$ are isomorphic. Again this is functorial and gives a *downward functor* $\downarrow (-):\mathcal{C}^{\operatorname{op}}\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$-$\mathbf{Vect}$.

My functors $F$ and $G$ are then $F=U\circ \uparrow(-)$, $G=\downarrow (-)$ where $U:\mathbb{R}$-$\mathbf{Alg}\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$-$\mathbf{Vect}$ is a forgetful functor. The diagram above is then a categorical representation of Theorem 2.8.

Comment: Your map $a \otimes b \mapsto a b$ does not make sense. Since when does a _vector space_ come with a bilinear multiplication?

Comment: Sorry - by this map I mean the unique *linear* map induced by the *bilinear* map $F(X)\times G(X)\rightarrow G(X)$, $(a,b)\mapsto a b$ by the universal property of the tensor product.

Comment: I'm saying that the expression $a b$ is meaningless.

Comment: Ah! I have got myself confused as my vector spaces $F(X)$ also carry an $\mathbb{R}$-algebra structure which I've neglected to mention. I will edit the question when I've fixed this (and probably when I'm more awake). Thanks for pointing this out and sorry for the mistake.

Comment: From what you've said, your diagram would also make sense if you replaced the bottom row $G(Y) \overset{G(\eta)}{\to} G(X)$ with $F(Y) \overset{F(\eta)}{\leftarrow} F(X)$. Does this modified diagram also commute?

Comment: @tcamps I'm not sure - I will check tomorrow and comment back, although I have a feeling that it doesn't. What I do know is that $G(\eta) F(\eta)\neq\operatorname{id}_{F(X)}$.

Comment: Why don't you just tell us what your functors are?

Comment: @QiaochuYuan I've edited the question to include the definitions of the functors, but I'm not sure if it will be particularly helpful. I was hoping that there might be something general going on which didn't require some quite complicated descriptions.

Comment: @tcamps I've checked and the modified diagram doesn't commute, unfortunately